# Hibernate Many To one 3 table involved

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, many-to-one

I'm starting with hibernate and I having some difficulties to build a easy
relationship of tables

, hibernate throw  nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Unable to find column with logical name: USERNAME in org.hibernate.mapping.Table(USER_FILESYSTEM) and its related supertables and secondary tables

I have this model

USER--1---N-->USER_FILE_SYSTEM--1--N-->USER_FS_THUMBS

All column name on DB squema are OK the column username" exists on table USER_FILESYSTEM
and table user

Table Users

```
    @Entity
@Table(name = "USERS")
public class Users implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "USERNAME", nullable = false, length = 15)
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "PASSWORD", nullable = false, length = 64)
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "FIRSTNAME", length = 32)
    private String firstname;

    @Column(name = "LASTNAME", length = 32)
    private String lastname;

    @Column(name = "EMAIL", nullable = false, length = 60)
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "TELEPHONE", length = 50)
    private String telephone;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "USER_ROLE",
            joinColumns = {
                @JoinColumn(name = "USERNAME_ID", referencedColumnName = "USERNAME")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {
                @JoinColumn(name = "ROL_ID", referencedColumnName = "ROL")}
    )
    private Rol role;

    @OneToMany(
            fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "username"
    )
    private Set<UserFileSystem> fileSystem;
```

Table UserFileSystem

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER_FILESYSTEM")
public class UserFileSystem implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "USERNAME", nullable = false)
    private Users username;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "SERVICE_ID", nullable = false, length = 10)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer serviceId;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "SERVICE_FOLDER", nullable = false, length = 64)
    private String serviceFolder;

    @Column(name = "PROTOCOL", length = 20)
    private String protocol;

    @Column(name = "PARAMS", length = 512)
    private String params;

    @OneToMany(
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "userFileSystemThumbsPK"
    )
    private Set<UserFileSystemThumbs> fileSystemThumbs;
```

Table UserFileSystemThumbs

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER_FS_THUMBS")
public class UserFileSystemThumbs implements Serializable {

    @EmbeddedId
    private UserFileSystemThumbsPK userFileSystemThumbsPK;

    @Column(name = "SERVICE_URL", nullable = false)
    private String serviceUrl;

    @Column(name = "CONTENT", nullable = false)
    private byte[] content;

    @Column(name = "MIME_TYPE", nullable = false)
    private String mimeType;
```

Primary key entity UserFileSystemThumbs

```
    @Embeddable
    public class UserFileSystemThumbsPK implements Serializable {

        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name = "USERNAME", nullable = false, referencedColumnName = "USERNAME"),
            @JoinColumn(name = "SERVICE_ID", nullable = false, referencedColumnName = "SERVICE_ID")
        })
        private UserFileSystem userFileSystem;

        @Column(name = "SERVICE_URL_HASH", nullable = false)
        private String serviceUrlHash;
Constructor equals hash....
```

the problem I think that UserFileSystemThumbsPK  USERNAME column do reference to UserFileSystem but in this table the column USERNAME is provided by users.

Comment: Instead of editing your question, just add an answer and accept it (you might have to wait some time for this)

Answer (score 0):

*Solution by OP.*

I changed

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER_FILESYSTEM")
public class UserFileSystem implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "USERNAME", nullable = false)
    private Users username;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "SERVICE_ID", nullable = false, length = 10)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer serviceId;
}
```

for this

```
 @Entity
    @Table(name = "USER_FILESYSTEM")
    public class UserFileSystem implements Serializable {

        @EmbeddedId
        private UserFileSystemID userFSID;
}
```

and I created the object UserFileSystemID with 2 values of PK

It's working like a champ!